# Difference between data_type(length) (length specifed) and data_type __ (No length specifed) in SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqldatatypes

What is difference between data_type(length) (length specifed) 
and data_type __ (No length specifed) in SQL

**For example**:-Datetime2(7) and datetime2

I mean what is the default length taken by sql

Comment: [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx) is your friend.

Comment: Thank you for help. It doesn't mention what value(length) it considers if we don't specify the length.

Comment: From that same link: "0 to 7 digits, with an accuracy of 100ns. The default precision is 7 digits."

Comment: Thank you guys.
Just confirming it means 
datetime2 = datetime2(7) right?
similarly it varies for other datatypes.Depends on document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must look at the documentation for each variable length type: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms187752%28v=sql.120%29.aspx)

It is always better to specify the correct length that is requiered for your data. You can also Alter the column later on if the requierements change it happen to be too big or too small.

They all have different default value, option and special cases.
You have to read it carefully because for 1 given type, the default length may vary. With char and varchar:

> When n is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration statement, the default length is ***1***. When n is not specified when using the CAST and CONVERT functions, the default length is ***30***.

You can also use sp_help to know the maximun length and precision among other info for a type:

```
sp_help datetime2

Type_name | Storage_type | Length | Prec | Scale | Nullable | Default_name | Rule_name | Collation
datetime2 | datetime2    | 8      | 27   | 7     | yes      | none         | none      | NULL
```